# Django long running asynchronous view blocking other requests in the server

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need help
I have been trying to solve a problem for a long time now
I want my django project to send some data which it would obtain from another url
but the data would be sent in batches. However all have done seems to be blocking other
request or operation which I want to do.
I have tried to make it an async function but it keeps on blocking other request

```
view.py

async def asyncTest():
    print('inside asyncTest sleep')
    await asyncio.sleep(20)#purpose of this is ensure that other request can recieve response
    print('inside asyncTest wakeup')
    ..do some other operations
    
@sync_to_async
def send_invitation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"result":"msg_type"}),
            #****Other things I have tried
            #
            #loop.run_until_complete(sync_to_async(asyncTest())), 
            #loop.run_until_complete(asyncTest()), 
            #asyncio.run(asyncTest()), 
            #asyncio.run(sync_to_async(asyncTest())), 
            #asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(asyncTest())),
            #asyncio.run(asyncio.coroutine(asyncTest())),
            #loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(asyncTest())),
            #***
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(
            asyncTest())), 
            content_type ="application/json",  status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

when it gets to asynctest where the sleep is, i try to open another view, the server does not respond.
Please can I do to make my program respond asynchronously to other request.

**Update**

settings.py
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'project_name.asgi.application'

there is nothing for wsgi in the setting.py
and I have checked using `os.environ.get('SERVER_GATEWAY_INTERFACE')` it shows I am using asynchronous

Comment: A few things. Looks like your app is using WSGI(?), so you won't get the benefits of a "global" event loop when running async functions. You run your task in a new event loop using [`loop.run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete), this blocks until the passed task is complete, when the task sleeps for 20 seconds you are just blocking the main thread for longer as there is nothing else scheduled in that event loop.

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated the question. Is there a code i can use to find out if my project is running wsgi or asgi? I have tried to do every i know to do

Comment: @IainShelvington Base on your comment I should not use loop.run_until_complete? so please how can i let the program be async?

Comment: @IainShelvington Please I would appreciate whatever help you would give me.

WSGI(?)!!! I checked to see what gatewayserver I was using and it shows it was asynchronous.I hope I am not missing something

Comment: If your webserver/app is running under ASGI/async then your view should be async instead of sync with `sync_to_async` and call your function with `await asyncTest()`, don't create a new event loop at all

Comment: @IainShelvington I have tried everything but it is still not working I do not know what to do anymore